# C++ OpenGL SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Recently I started to learn SFML library and how to make simple games. Then I decided to make very simple animation. Electron which moves around the atom. I used this formula

```
x = x0 + radius*sin(angle);
y = y0 + radius*cos(angle);
```

where x, y - object coordinates, x0, y0 - coordinates of the center

I made something but I have some problems. I couldn't see my electron and this movement around the atom. I think that I should use loop for moving but I'm not sure.

This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
   float xo = 250;//координаты центра(coordinates of the center)
   float yo = 250;//координаты центра(coordinates of the center)

   float radius = 10;//радиус

   float k = 0.0f;//время(time)

   float x = 130;//координаты объекта(object coordinates)
   float y = 330;//координаты объекта(object coordinates)

   float rotation = 5.0;

   //float x = 1000 / 2;
   //float y = 1000 / 2;

   float alpha = 0;//угол(angle)

   RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 1000), "Atom");
   window.setFramerateLimit(60);

   Clock clock;
   sf::Event windowEvent;

   Texture herotexture;
   herotexture.loadFromFile("atom_image.png");

   Sprite herosprite;
   herosprite.setTexture(herotexture);
   //herosprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 99, 48, 51));//получили нужный нам прямоугольник с котом
   herosprite.setPosition(250, 250); //выводим спрайт в позицию x y (output the sprite to the position x y)

   CircleShape circle;
   circle.setRadius(radius);
   circle.setOutlineColor(Color::Red);
   circle.setOutlineThickness(5);
   circle.setPosition(x, y);
   circle.setRotation(0);

   bool track;

   while (window.isOpen())
   {
       Event event;
       while (window.pollEvent(event))
       {
           if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
               window.close();
       }

       circle.rotate(rotation);

       //alpha++; 
       alpha+=deltaTime*k;
       x = xo + radius*sin(alpha);//формула для движения по окружности(formula for motion along a circle)
       y = yo + radius*cos(alpha);//формула для движения по окружности(formula for motion along a circle)

      //Vector2f direction(x, y);
      //float speed = 20.0f;

      //circle.move(direction * k * speed);
      circle.move(x, y);

      /*(if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left)) { herosprite.move(-0.1, 0); } //первая координата Х отрицательна =>идём влево
      if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right)) { herosprite.move(0.1, 0); } //первая координата Х положительна =>идём вправо
      if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Up)) { herosprite.move(0, -0.1); } //вторая координата (У) отрицательна =>идём вверх (вспоминаем из предыдущих уроков почему именно вверх, а не вниз)
      if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Down)) { herosprite.move(0, 0.1); } //вторая координата (У) положительна =>идём вниз (если не понятно почему именно вниз - смотрим предыдущие уроки)
      */
      window.clear();
      window.draw(herosprite);
      window.draw(circle);
      k = clock.restart().asSeconds();
      window.display();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Some @StarShine corrections:

```
circle.rotate(rotation); 
x = xo + radius*sin(alpha); //формула для движения по окружности(formula for motion along a circle) 
y = yo + radius*cos(alpha); //формула для движения по окружности(formula for motion along a circle) 
Vector2f direction(x, y); 
float speed = 20.0f; 
circle.move(direction * k * speed);
```

Comment: Sin and cos generally take radians, so incrementing the angle 'alpha' with 1 will jump around on the unit circle.

Comment: @StarShine oh I mixed up. Because I must to use `alpha+=deltaTime*k` it's angle change with time. And I tried to use clock but I got an error cuase alpha has value float and clock - Clock. But I don't understand how to use formulas. Shoud I use the loop for this or how?

Comment: Documentation at https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Clock.php says you can call the restart() function once before the loop, and poll the elapsed number of seconds using getElapsedTime (), so you could write 'angle = clock.getElapsedTime() * rotationSpeed;'.

Comment: @StarShine yeah I read about it but compiler said me that there is no suitable function to convert sf::Time to float cause my alpha is float. By the way I tried differently to do it using Vector2f. But it didn't work. Maybe I didn't understan something.
`circle.rotate(rotation);
  x = xo + radius*sin(alpha);//формула для движения по окружности(formula for motion along a circle)
  

y = yo + radius*cos(alpha);//формула для движения по окружности(formula for motion along a circle)

  Vector2f direction(x, y);
  float speed = 20.0f;

  circle.move(direction * k * speed);`

Comment: Are you serious? Read the docs! https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Time.php states that sf::Time objects have methods to convert time into float. I'm not gonna type it for you.

Comment: @StarShine I made something. Now it looks like this

Comment: @StarShine I conveted time and changed my radius. Cause before it was the radius of my circle not the radius of movement

Comment: @StarShine you can see my code on my answer. Cause I can't add code on comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
   float xo = 250;//координаты центра(coordinates of the center)
   float yo = 250;//координаты центра(coordinates of the center)

   float radius = 10;//радиус

   float k = 0.0f;//время(time)

   float x = 130;//координаты объекта(object coordinates)
   float y = 330;//координаты объекта(object coordinates)

   float rotation = 5.0;

  /*float x = 1000 / 2;
   float y = 1000 / 2;*/

  float alpha = 0;//угол(angle)

  float speed = 200.0f;

  RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1000, 1000), "Atom");
  window.setFramerateLimit(60);

  Clock clock;
  sf::Event windowEvent;

  Texture herotexture;
  herotexture.loadFromFile("atom_image.png");

  Sprite herosprite;
  herosprite.setTexture(herotexture);
//herosprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 99, 48, 51));//получили нужный нам прямоугольник с котом
  herosprite.setPosition(250, 250); //выводим спрайт в позицию x y (output the sprite to the position x y)

  CircleShape circle;
  circle.setRadius(radius);
  circle.setOutlineColor(Color::Red);
  circle.setOutlineThickness(5);
  circle.setPosition(x, y);
  circle.setRotation(0);


  while (window.isOpen())
  {
       Event event;
       while (window.pollEvent(event))
       {
           if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
               window.close();
       }

      /*circle.rotate(rotation);

      alpha = (float)clock.getElapsedTime().asMicroseconds() * k;*/

      float Radius = sqrt(pow(((float)circle.getPosition().x - (float)herosprite.getPosition().x), 2.0f) + pow(((float)circle.getPosition().y - (float)herosprite.getPosition().y), 2.0f));

      clock.restart();
      k = k / 800;
      float deltaTime = clock.restart().asSeconds();

      alpha += deltaTime*(float)clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();

      cout << "\nGet Position Atom is -> " << (float)herosprite.getPosition().x << endl;
      cout << "\nGet Position Circle is -> " << (float)circle.getPosition().x << endl;
      cout << "\nRadius is -> " << Radius << endl;

      x = xo + Radius*cos(alpha) * speed;//формула для движения по окружности(formula for motion along a circle)
      y = yo + Radius*sin(alpha) * speed;//формула для движения по окружности(formula for motion along a circle)
      cout << "x is -> " << x << endl;
      Vector2f direction(x, y);

      circle.move(direction * deltaTime * speed);

      if (sqrt(pow(((float)circle.getPosition().x - (float)herosprite.getPosition().x), 2.0f) + pow(((float)circle.getPosition().y - (float)herosprite.getPosition().y), 2.0f)) > (float)herosprite.getPosition().x && sqrt(pow(((float)circle.getPosition().x - (float)herosprite.getPosition().x), 2.0f) + pow(((float)circle.getPosition().y - (float)herosprite.getPosition().y), 2.0f)) > (float)herosprite.getPosition().y)
      {
           circle.move(-direction * deltaTime * speed);
           float cd = circle.getPosition().x + 40;
           circle.move(cd, circle.getPosition().y);
           circle.setPosition(130, 330);
      }


      /*circle.move(direction);
      circle.move(x, y);*/

      window.clear();
      window.draw(herosprite);
      window.draw(circle);
      window.display();
  }

  return 0;
}
```